# Login problem in NPM after clear browser history

Tags: node.js, npm

Kindly help me
I am not loging in npm after clear browser history and then I changed my password several time but result is same. I tried from cmd terminal also but it gave a error. I attached the screenshot also.

Kindly give the solution.